# qt4 tab update function?

Tags: python-3.x, pyside

At the moment, I have multiple tabs that displays a different database in each tab. There is also a form in each of the tab that allows you create and delete entries inside the tables. In the creation form, the comboboxes' selection are determined from the other databases. The problem that I have is that if I were to add a new entry into the first database, it wouldn't update the comboboxes' selection with the updated database. I'm thinking that qt possibly has a action call that will trigger every time a tab is change but I cannot find it. If it doesn't have this, what would be the best way to implement this?

```
Database A
|Names|Type|Location
|Abc  |B   |Somewhere
|Acb  |C   |Other place

Database B
|Type|Area|Horizontal?
|B  |Alpha   |Yes
|C  |Bravo   |No
```

Each of the database are contained in 2 different tabs. Currently, when inserting a new entry into Database A, there would be a textfield for Names, a combobox for Type which contains only B and C, and textfield for location. After creating another entry in Database B (For instance type C), I want to go back to the tab in database A where the combobox gets updated to say A,B, and C.

Comment: How do you add a new entry into a database ? If  you fill the textfield and combobox and click an "add entry" button, this button could also update the other tabs.

Comment: I insert a new entry into the database by calling ```self.db.insert(self.table_name, self.insert_fields, self.insert_values)```. The combo boxes are all being populated by ```self.fields_combo_box["item"][0].addItems(db.populate_combo(table="item", field="itemName"))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there is a signal in Qt that is called `currentChanged(int index)`. I simply connected that signal with my own custom function that updates my tabs and it works now! 
Here is an example of what I did.

```
self.tabs = QTabWidget()
self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.reloadData)

@QtCore.Slot()
def reloadData(self):
    # Reload data calls goes here
```